# SQL Query to find who are born until the year 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, tuples

> Two relationships are given:
> **Employee** (*AngID, Name, Surname, Date of Birth, Gender, Education, Position, Monthly Salary, DepID*)
> **Department** (*DepID, DepName, City*)

> Print the SQL statement or statements that solve the following problem:
> To display the number of employees according to the year of birth, who are born until the year 2000. The following will be displayed: Year, Number. The tuples will be ordered in descending order of the year of birth.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Year, Number
FROM Employee
WHERE Date of Birth <2000 AS Num
ORDER BY Date of Birth DESC
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your statement. `WHERE Date of Birth` and `ORDER BY Date of Birth` aren't valid, as you need to delimit identify your column's name. `Date of Birth <2000` (if it were identified) would unlikely be incorrect, as `2000` is *not* a `date`. `<2000 AS Num` isn't valid, as you don't alias columns in the `FROM`. Also your table `Employee` (according to the description) has no columns `Number` or `Year`.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is just counting the number of employees per year of birth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is the query you are after:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateofBirth) as Year, Count(1) AS NumberOfEmployees
FROM Employee
WHERE DateofBirth < '2000-01-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(DateofBirth)
ORDER BY YEAR(DateofBirth) DESC
```

This query will filter all employees who were born before year 2000. It will group the records by year and present the count.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c53a4/7) example

Comment: I'd recommend using an actual date for the `WHERE`. Using `YEAR` on the `DateofBirth` column won't be SARGable.

Comment: @Larnu thanks fixed

Comment: What means Count(1)?

Comment: @MarcelinaBulai counting all records who met the criteria.

Comment: @Elad Thanks a lot!

Comment: No need to use `cast()`

Comment: @Shmiel True. wasn't sure about the sql sever syntax. i doubled check and updated the answer

Comment: I'd suggest aliasing the `Count(1)`, perhaps `Count(1) AS NumberOfEmployees`

Comment: @Andrew agree. explicit name for columns is important

Answer (score 0):

> To display the number of employees

```
COUNT(*)

FROM Employee emp
```

> according to the year of birth

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date of Birth])
```

> who are born until the year 2000.

```
WHERE [Date of Birth] < '2001-01-01'
```

> The following will be displayed: Year, Number.

```
DATEPART(YEAR, [Date of Birth]) AS [Year], 
COUNT(*) AS [Number]
```

> The tuples will be ordered in descending order of the year of birth.

```
ORDER BY [Year] DESC
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, [Date of Birth]) AS [Year] 
, COUNT(*) AS [Number] 
FROM Employee emp
WHERE [Date of Birth] < '2001-01-01' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, [Date of Birth]) 
ORDER BY [Year] DESC
```

Comment: Fiddle link is broken `23503ERROR: insert or update on table "history" violates foreign key constraint "history_rdbms_code_fkey" DETAIL: Key (rdbms_code, sample_name, fiddle_hash)=(sqlserver_2019, , \x5ee2bd537bb85b37f168bad5106fbedf) is not present in table "fiddle". CONTEXT: SQL function "loghistory" statement 1`

Comment: I think that is the fault of db<>fiddle, *not* the user, @Andrew .

Comment: @Larnu Perhaps, but a bad link for whatever reason is still on the user to correct - either remove or redo with a fiddle that does properly exist (Which could be on either the site or the user depending on why the fiddle doesn't seem to exist)

Comment: Seems that there's a problem with linking to dbfiddle.uk when you use the sample database. Oh well. No fiddle then.